# Best way to make ReactiveAggregate reactive when data changes on a user

Tags: meteor

I am currently using ReactiveAggregate to find a subset of Product data, like this:

```
ReactiveAggregate(this, Products, [
            { $match: {}},
            { $project: {
              title: true,
              image: true,
              variants: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$variants",
                  as: "variant",
                  cond: {
                    $setIsSubset: [['$$variant.id'], user.variantFollowing]
                  }
                }
              }
            }}
          ], { clientCollection: 'aggregateVariants' }
```

As you can see, a variant is returned if `user.variantFollowing` matches. When a user 'follows' a product, the ID is added to their object. However, if I understand correctly, this is not triggering ReactiveAggregate to get the new subset when this happens. Only on a full page refresh do I get the correct (latest) data.

Is this the correct way to approach this?

I could store the user's ID as part of the Product object, but the way this would be stored would be nested two places, and I think I would need the Mongo 3.5 updates to then be able to accurately update this. So i'm looking for how to do this in Meteor 1.5+ / Mongo 3.2.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've been able to get there by adding `autorun` to the subscription of the aggregate collection, like this:

```
Template.followedProducts.onCreated(function() {
  Meteor.subscribe('products');

  this.autorun(() => {
    Meteor.subscribe('productsFollowed');
  });

... rest of function
```

For context, `productsFollowed` is the subscription to retrieve `aggregateVariants` from the original question.

Thanks to **robfallows** in this post: https://forums.meteor.com/t/when-and-how-to-use-this-autorun/26075/6